# JMETER playback

Tags: jmeter, performance

We are trying to playback our recorded test scripts but it always gets this response data:

`This document you requested has moved temporarily.`

We have tried removing "`javax.faces.ViewState`" in the request parameters across all the samplers, but it gives the same response data except for the login part of the script.

Any insights or if you could point me to any existing solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove this `javax.faces.ViewState`, you need to perform so called [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), i.e. extract the value of this "viewstate" hidden input, convert it into a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and add this variable to the next request.

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove that viewstate parameter, but you should make that variable.
That means you must put a value in that parameter you obtained from a previous response.

See for more information: http://sjpknight.com/correlating-dynamic-values-in-jmeter/